# Typescript inference for inner function parameter

Tags: typescript

```js
function makeBox<T, U extends () => (input: T) => number>(value: {
  t: T
  u: U
}) {
  return value
}

makeBox({
  t: 'ada',
  u: () => {
    return (input) => {
      return Number.parseInt(input)
    }
  },
})
```

This example will break, input will show up as `unknown`.

[image]

However, if we simply add a single argument to the function, it will all in a sudden start working

```js
function makeBox<T, U extends (noop: never) => (input: T) => number>(value: {
  t: T
  u: U
}) {
  return value
}

makeBox({
  t: 'ada',
  u: (_noop) => {
    return (input2) => {
      return Number.parseInt(input2)
    }
  },
})
```

[image]

Why is that? What's the logic behind this?

Comment: That's pretty strange. I can't imagine that's intended.

Comment: The [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlEO5m) doesn't show the same diagnostics as your screenshots. Can you include your TS version and your TSConfig?